# How to load js scripts from internet mentioned in html file from flask

Tags: python, css, flask

i have in my html file script location like
`<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js">`

now when i am using this in flask render_template("test.html"), i think it's not able to load these files over the internet which is why i don't see it loaded properly. what's the way to do in flask so that i can load all js, css over internet loaded properly.

please help.
thanks a lot,

Sudip

Comment: By downloading `fontawesome` and using `<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/fontawesome.min.js') }}"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `defer` tag, and put the `script` tag in the header.  That makes sure it will load before you need it.  When deferred, your page loaded first, so the font was not available yet:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js">
</head>
```